# How to bind a CursorAdapter to an ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-cursoradapter

I can now bind a **CursorAdapter** to a `ListView`. And the ListView can update automatically when the **database** is modified.

For the data rows in the database has a field 'type', they can be 'Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', .etc. And I want to display the rows in **ExpandableListView**, so that every type of rows can group together. And I also want the ExpandableListView can update automatically when the database is modified.
How can I combine the **CursorAdapter** and **ExpandableListView** together?

I googled a lot, but cannot find a solution, thank you for your attention!

Comment: Is there a reason to not use one of the platform's adapters specially designed for an `ExpandableListView`?

Comment: No, I should use CursorTreeAdapter. But I only get to know it just now! @Luksprog

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's referred to as a `CursorTreeAdapter`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.html